# Run a separate query for each ID found in the array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Trying to run a second query for items in an array. 
First I've created an array of user information, then for each of the users I need to query for their answers found in the answers table.

The idea is for the array to have data from the first query and then simply add the data from the answers to the related user element.  The code below is only listing the first system.

I've been so reluctant to post my question here, but my entire day has been consumed by this and I'm getting no where fast. Apologies in advance for my obviously flawed approach.

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [fname] => asdf
            [lname] => asdf
            [minitial] => a
            [rank] => MAJ
            [uniq] => !s5$qn

            [sysName] = System 1 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom

            [sysName] = System 2 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom

            [sysName] = System 3 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom


   [1] => Array
        (
            [fname] => asdf
            [lname] => lkjlkj
            [minitial] => i
            [rank] => oiuoi
            [uniq] => @z26dr

            [sysName] = System 1 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom

            [sysName] = System 2 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom

            [sysName] = System 3 Name
            [choice] = The choice for This named system
            [priority] = The priority 
            [termcom] = The termcom


        )
```

//CODE

```
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname, minitial, rank, uniq FROM `user` join answers on answers.uniqid = user.uniq";
$data = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("MySQL ERROR: ". mysqli_error($con));

$users = array();
$i = 0;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $users['answers'][$i] = array (
        "fname" => $row['fname'], 
        "lname" => $row['lname'], 
        "minitial" => $row['minitial'], 
        "rank" => $row['rank'], 
        "uniq" => $row['uniq']
     );

    $query2 = "SELECT a.sysid, s.sysName, uniqid, choice, priority, termcom FROM answers a LEFT JOIN systems s ON s.sysID = a.sysid WHERE a.uniqid = '" . $row['uniq'] . "'";
    $data2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($data2, MYSQL_NUM))
    {       
        $users['answers'][$i]['sysName'] = $row2[1];
        $users['answers'][$i]['choice'] = $row2[3];     
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any insight you might share.

EDIT:  This is the array coming back, and only the first system is being listed for each user.

```
[2] => Array
        (
            [fname] => asdf
            [lname] => lkjlkj
            [minitial] => i
            [rank] => oiuoi
            [uniq] => @z26dr
            [sysName] => Super Terminate System
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [fname] => Juuu
            [lname] => kjuuu
            [minitial] => k
            [rank] => LTC
            [uniq] => gthdz%
            [sysName] => Super Terminate System
        )
```

Comment: Have you tried writing one single SQL statement to return something closer to the final result-set?  Could even use some sub selects if you can't get the joins figured out.  It might be a simpler approach.

Comment: Also, what is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: @goodmood2 Well, there's http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for that, I think?

Comment: It's not listing all of the items found by the second query for each user.

Comment: @lethal-guitar for me this? i dont need review. maybe OP need it.

Comment: I have not tried to do this using all SQL, it is certainly worth a shot.  Thanks for that @ficuscr

Comment: @goodmood: That's what I meant. You said: "he just told you to think if its nice [the code]". So I meant to say "then he might consider posting on codereview instead".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O.K. you don't exactly tell what happens when you run your script (What is the Problem). But when i look at your coude i can assume what is going wrong.

First of all, I think you could also do it with on query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` 
        join answers on answers.uniqid = user.uniq
        LEFT JOIN systems s ON s.sysID = a.sysid";
```

Hopefully this helps. Otherwise:

In your second query there is a problem. I think you should change:

```
$query2 = "SELECT a.sysid, s.sysName, uniqid, choice, priority, termcom FROM answers a LEFT JOIN systems s ON s.sysID = a.sysid WHERE a.uniqid = '" . $row['uniq'] . "'";
```

to

```
$query2 = "SELECT a.sysid, s.sysName, s.uniqid, s.choice, s.priority, s.termcom FROM answers a LEFT JOIN systems s ON s.sysID = a.sysid WHERE a.uniqid = '" . $row['uniq'] . "'";
```

The s. before choice = s.choice

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @rechengehirn


I have a table of users, a table of systems, and a table of answers. I'm trying to return an array, of a single user and their details, then for each uID found in that array, query for all of the systems and choices they've made.


If I group the SQL by uid(userid), I get only one user (good) back and the first system.


So theoretically, I'm trying to create an array of usernames and their user id, then for each uid in that array, run another query to get the system name and the choices they made for it.

Comment: Right now, I'm only getting one system added to the array.

Comment: Well I didn't learn what I'm doing wrong, but I certainly appreciate the look!

I'll just move on and do it a half-assed sorta working way via SQL.